# python CSVファイル作成コード　チェックのお願い

Tags: python, python3

r_file.txtを1行ずつ読み込み、w_file.csvファイル（CSVファイル）にしました。
目的は実現できておりますが、もっと、コードを短くすることや、もっと改善するべき箇所を
アドバイスいただければと思います。

r_file.txt↓

```
Tue Nov 11 00:00:00 JST 2022
12 aaa bbb cc:cc:cc:cc ddd
34 eee fff gg:gg:gg:gg hhh

Tue Nov 11 00:00:05 JST 2022
78 iii jjj kk:kk:kk:kk lll
99 mmm nnn oo:oo:oo:oo ppp

Tue Nov 11 00:00:10 JST 2022
12 qqq rrr ss:ss:ss:ss ttt
34 uuu vvv ww:ww:ww:ww zzz
```

w_file.csv↓

```
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,12,aaa,bbb,cc:cc:cc:cc,ddd
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,34,eee,fff,gg:gg:gg:gg,hhh
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:05,78,iii,jjj,kk:kk:kk:kk,lll
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:05,99,mmm,nnn,oo:oo:oo:oo,ppp
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:10,12,qqq,rrr,ss:ss:ss:ss,ttt
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:10,34,uuu,vvv,ww:ww:ww:ww,zzz
```

```py
# test.py

import csv

read_file = "r_file.txt"
write_file = "w_file.csv"


with open(write_file, "w", encoding="utf_8", newline="") as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    
    with open(read_file, "r", encoding="utf_8") as f:
        line = f.readline()
        
        while line:
            if line.startswith("Tue"):
                
                # JST 2022を除去
                data = line.split()[:4]
            
            # 列の開始が数字か確認
            if line[0] >= '0' and line[0] <= '9':
                elem = line.split()
                
                # 年月と時間を一番左に追記するため以下の処理を実施
                csv_data = data + elem
                
                writer.writerow(csv_data)
                
            line = f.readline()
```

Comment: ご本人自身がどのような点を改善したいかを明確にしてもらった方が良い質問になる気がします。今の質問の仕方だと[主観性が高い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) と判断される可能性もあります。 / メタでの関連討論も参照してください。 - [「コードをブラッシュアップする方法を教えてください」系の質問をするときに気をつけるべき点を教えてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3807)

Comment: 主観性はどうでもいいのですが、どういう意図のコードなのかが分からないとブラッシュアップも何もない気がします。
一言で言えば、質問者本人がまず最大限合理的なロジックに出来ていることが必要です。そうすれば全く同じ動作をするより良いコードは書ける人がいると思います。もし無理なら、仕様的な意図を説明する文章が必要だと思いますよ。
あとは環境その他規模感や制約なども書いた方がいいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

曜日のアルファベット固定するのはどうかと思うので, 数字か改行かの判断で

```py
import csv
import string
import io

text = '''
Tue Nov 11 00:00:00 JST 2022
12 aaa bbb cc:cc:cc:cc ddd
34 eee fff gg:gg:gg:gg hhh

Tue Nov 11 00:00:05 JST 2022
78 iii jjj kk:kk:kk:kk lll
99 mmm nnn oo:oo:oo:oo ppp

Tue Nov 11 00:00:10 JST 2022
12 qqq rrr ss:ss:ss:ss ttt
34 uuu vvv ww:ww:ww:ww zzz
'''

def func(fp):
    for ln in fp:
        if ln[0] in string.digits:
            yield data +ln.split()
        elif ln[0] != '\n':
            data = ln.split()[:4]

#with io.StringIO(text) as fp, open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
with (io.StringIO(text) as fp,
      io.StringIO() as csvfile):
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(func(fp))

    res = csvfile.getvalue()
print(res)
# Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,12,aaa,bbb,cc:cc:cc:cc,ddd
# Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,34,eee,fff,gg:gg:gg:gg,hhh
# Tue,Nov,11,00:00:05,78,iii,jjj,kk:kk:kk:kk,lll
# Tue,Nov,11,00:00:05,99,mmm,nnn,oo:oo:oo:oo,ppp
# Tue,Nov,11,00:00:10,12,qqq,rrr,ss:ss:ss:ss,ttt
# Tue,Nov,11,00:00:10,34,uuu,vvv,ww:ww:ww:ww,zzz
```

##### 追記 `func()`

`def func(fp)` について (コメントより)

以下のようにすると, `rows`を得ることができ
関数内で listを準備し returnで返しても, ほぼ同じような処理内容になります

```py
with (io.StringIO(text) as fp,
      io.StringIO() as csvfile):
    rows = list(func(fp))
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(rows)

#   writer.writerows([func(fp)])   # ⇐ 結果的に rows用意するのと同じ
```

この場合 先の `func()` では以下の違いがあります

- `rows`を用意しないことで記憶域を無駄にしない。例えば, 蓄えると主記憶を圧迫するような大量のデータであっても逐次処理可能
- `yield` 見慣れてる人にとっては分かりやすい (かも)

Comment: 有難うございます。
def fn(fp):の中身が難しすぎます。。。

Comment: ジェネレーターで, 要素をひとつずつ順に返してるだけですが, どの辺りがわからないかが書いてあると説明しやすいかも(関数名少し変えました)

Comment: わざわざyieldを使うならレコード単位にするロジックだけにした方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

空行で分割。

```py
import csv
from itertools import takewhile

read_file = 'r_file.txt'
write_file = 'w_file.csv'

with open(read_file, 'r', encoding='utf_8') as f, \
     open(write_file, 'w', encoding='utf_8', newline='') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    while (line := [*takewhile(lambda l: l[0]!='\n', f)]):
        prefix = line[0].split()[:4]
        output = [prefix + l.split() for l in line[1:] if '0' <= l[0] <= '9']
        if output: writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: Tue判定などが再現できていません。newlineは説明した方がいいでしょう。

Comment: あと:=が3.8～と比較的新しい機能なので、動かない環境もありそうです。

Answer (score 0):

将来このソースコードを基に仕様変更したり新しく類似のものを作るのであれば，例えば1ヶ月後の自分にとって内容を理解し易くしておくこと（可読性の向上）は改善と言えます。
そこで，1ヶ月後に私が読むと想定してコードを拝見すると，「読み込み -> 加工 -> 書き込み」と処理を分けて記述しておきたくなります。なお，下記は入力ファイルが4行単位であることを前提にした記述例です。
（追記）
また，オリジナルとは異なり記述例では入力ファイルの大きさに比例してメモリ消費が増えます。

```
import csv

read_file = 'r_file.txt'
write_file = 'w_file.csv'

with open(read_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = [x.split() for x in f.read().splitlines()]

rows = []
for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
    time_info = data[i][:4]
    rows.append(time_info + data[i+1])
    rows.append(time_info + data[i+2])

with open(write_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n').writerows(rows)
```

Comment: この形だとrowsが大きくなりすぎ、大きなデータをストリーム処理できなくなっています。

Comment: 一応，回答する前に 1,200,000行で確認（計算時間は約2.2秒）したのですが，後学のためにどのような環境でどのくらいのデータ量でストリーム処理できなくなったのか教えていただけると幸いです。ちなみに私の環境は大したことなくて「 macOS13(M1, 8GB), Python 3.10.8 」です。

Comment: あなたの環境の問題ではありません。pythonなんて今どきマイコン基板でも動かしますし、web上のwasmかもしれません。ブラッシュアップして制限が増えるのは論外ですよ。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。コメントの主旨を理解することができました。